# Atollic TrueSTUDIO: How to convert from C to C++?

Tags: c++, stm32, truestudio

I try to convert my project to C++ in TrueSTUDIO for STM32 by

- Selecting project (in C/C++ Projects tab)
- Right mouse button, select New/Other
- In C/C++ tab, Convert to a C/C++ Project (Adds C/C++ Nature)
- When pressing Next, nothing happens (unclear why)
- When I press Next again, I see: Convert to a C/C++ project: The wizards adds C/C++  Nature to the selected projects to enable C/C++ Tools Supports for them
- I press Finish

Than nothing happens, when I change main.c to main.cpp, I get the following error after build:

```
startup\startup_stm32f407xx.o: In function `LoopFillZerobss':
C:\Users\Michel\OneDrive\Stm32\Stm32CubeProjects\Fcb1010\Debug/..\startup/startup_stm32f407xx.s:115: undefined reference to `main'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems still C is used (also in the command line (first part):

```
arm-atollic-eabi-gcc -o Fcb1010.elf Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal.o Drivers\STM ...
```

I would expect g++ to be used.

How to change my settings/procedure to be able to use C++ within TrueSTUDIO for a CubeMX generated project?

**UPDATE**

I removed Atollic TrueStudio, removed AC6 System Workbench, and reinstalled AC6 System Workbench. Now I can use C++ at AC6 System Workbench, even using STL.

I do not dare to install Atollic TrueStudio again, since it breaks the existing installation of AC6 SystemWorkbench, probably because they both use Eclipse. A pity, since I liked some features of TrueStudio, but C++ is more important to me. So for me, no TrueStudio anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you mention

> startup\startup_stm32f407xx.o: In function 'LoopFillZerobss':
>   C:\Users\Michel\OneDrive\Stm32\Stm32CubeProjects\Fcb1010\Debug/..\startup/startup_stm32f407xx.s:115: undefined reference to `main'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Is a linker problem, I suspect the library is looking for a c main function. A C++ compiler performs name mangling, so the symbol will no longer be `main`.

Try changing the signature of your `main` to `extern "C" int main(void)`

Comment: I tried it, nothing changed, however, it seemed that the entire file was not taken into account. I'm still checking how to fix this. So I have to postpone the acceptance until I'm sure the problem will be solved.

Comment: I continued with the problem, but I cannot get it working, it still seems that the cpp file is not taken into account.

Comment: Is the cpp file being compiled. Add a `#error "testing"` to the top of it to see.

Comment: I made on purpose an error in the cpp file and the compiler missed the compilation in the file, since the linker gave the same error. Hopefully a reinstall will work (of the entire Eclipse environment).

Comment: I gave the bounty to you, although it didn't solve the problem. I will update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps:-

1. Better convert all the .c file to .cpp manually
2. Check each header file and change macro which is specific to C language
3. change the main function from C type to C++ (void main to int main()) also return a value from your main function.
4. If you are using a make file check if specific C dependencies are referred and change them.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I did this already in an earlier stage, but did not help.  A makefile is not used (or at least not visible).